# Android: Wrap Content naturally in a linear layout or relative layout etc

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

Is there a layout in Android that will naturally wrap content?

I can obviously try and programmatically measure how much space there is but I'd rather avoid that as much as possible.

Here is a simple diagram. In my code all of the ImageViews have a fixed width of 48dp. Obviously I don't know how many columns there will be, otherwise I'd use a table view or something, so I'm looking for something that can just naturally wrap once displayed on the screen.

High Density Screen

```
|            |            |
| ImageView1 | ImageView2 |
|            |            |
```

Medium Density Screen

```
|            |          
| ImageView1 | 
|            |
--------------
| ImageView2 |  
|            |
|            |
```

Comment: I don't think there is something like that in android. However, Romain Guy did one of those LayoutOut during a presentation that uses the technic you describe and work okay. You can google that video

Comment: Giving this a shot, seems promising

Answer (score 0):

This is possible to do you can use `GridLayout` and specify different Column counts for this on different device densities using:

```
GridLayout mGridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.myGridLayoutId);

// Do some check of device density and based on result do

DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
....
if(mDensity == metrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM){
    mGridlayout.setColumnCount(1);
}else if(mDensity == metrics.DENSITY_HIGH){

   mGridlayout.setColumnCount(2);
}
```

etc.

see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html

but there is nothing like a FlowLayout in Android, which can is used in Java Swing